# Giving Miracle Gro fertilzer to prayer plant

Tags: houseplants, indoors, fertilizer

The instructions on the Miracle Gro package says "Mix 1/4 tsp in 0.5 gallon water". Yet, the prayer plant [(Maranta leuconeura)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maranta_leuconeura) needs very little water every day (if at all) and fertilizer once every two weeks. So how much of the Miracle Gro fertilizer should be used?

Comment: What it says on the package. Mix up half a gallon, keep it in a container, and use it gradually. Plastic drinks bottles are a good source of "free" containers, *so long as there is no danger of somebody drinking the contents* - make sure they are labeled, kept away from children, etc.

Comment: By Prayer plant, do you mean Maranta? prayer  plant is sometimes used as a common name for other plants - and are you growing it as a houseplant,indoors, or outdoors in the ground?

Comment: @Bamboo yes, Maranta. Growing it as a houseplant, indoors.

Comment: I don't know what fertilizers are available where you are, but its much easier if you use a specialist houseplant fertlizer such as Baby Bio  -https://www.amazon.co.uk/Baby-Original-House-Plant-Food/dp/B000TROMB2 they're usually liquid,in small bottles, and you only need 5 drops to a pint of water. Trying to mix up a tiny amount of powder Miracle Gro will be very difficult...you'd have no choice but to mix it up and keep it for ages till its used up.